# 2 draw piles for convenience?

Tags: house-rules

Sometimes when the table is large enough, or people don't want to reach too far, a single draw pile is split into multiple draw piles.  This has always bothered me.

Does it bother anyone else?  Are there any statistical reasons to not split the draw pile?

Comment: Aside from cases where there is additional information available about the card(s) or something has manipulated the deck, it also shouldn't matter if a player draws from the bottom instead of the top of the deck.  Getting hung up about this type of thing ranks up there with the idea that dealing to the players out of order will give someone else "your" cards.  Random is random...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hypothetically, there's nothing wrong with splitting the draw pile. Splitting a randomized deck into multiple decks, won't affect the randomization. However, you need to carefully consider how you interact with the draw pile during the course of the game.

- Do cards ever get put back on top of,
  into, or under the draw pile? If so,
  having multiple draw piles would
  affect the game. For example, if
  players can put a card on top of the
  draw pile, can I choose to draw from
  either pile?
- What happens when the
  draw pile runs out? If the normal
  rule is to shuffle the discard pile
  to create a new draw pile, you
  probably need to wait until all draw
  piles run out before doing so.
- If    you have multiple draw piles,
  will    you also have multiple
  discard piles?    If so, you need to
  consider how you    interact with the
  discard pile, also.

Comment: Also, when we did this with a mixed older base set and newer expansion set in Race for the Galaxy, some players would opt to take the fresh card from either deck, which is obviously cheating.

Comment: @rob-renaud, when you say "fresh card", you mean a card that is obviously from the expansion because it is less worn/broken in?

Answer (score 11):

Cards are randomized through shuffling not through picking the draw pile. Statistically you should have the exactly same chances of drawing any particular card from either pile.

Answer (score 2):

We do that with some games (including tiles in Carcassonne), but you have to allow people to pull from either pile they want, and don't reshuffle until both piles have been depleted.

Comment: While I obviously agree when you say that all stacks/decks must be depleted before reshuffling, granting that each player may draw from either stack/deck is fair, polite, but not actually needed.

Answer (score 2):

When the table is inconveniently large and we are playing a game with a thick pack of cards, we sometimes spread the draw pile out into a large fan. That way, everyone can reach conveniently and anyone who suspects they may be disadvantaged can draw from any part of the pack. Myself, I can't see it makes any difference, but those who have some doubts can pick from anywhere and therefore have no grounds for suspicion.

Comment: The problem with that plan is that if (say) the ace of spades is dog-eared then anyone who knows that fact can choose to pick it (or avoid it), whereas in a 'normal' game the card goes to the person whose turn it is: this has to affect the game.

Answer (score 2):

While splitting the deck is statistically irrelevant, as others have said, it *does* affect those games in which you might have such options as "check the first X cards in the deck and put them as they were" (say, to simulate precognitions), "check the first X cards and reorder them as you wish" etc.